# How to add a Contact in SugarCRM to a TargetList/ProspectList using API?

Tags: php, rest, sugarcrm

I have a script in PHP that runs a few things automatically on SugarCRM using RestAPI.

I'm using this PHP Class to manage the RestAPI:
http://github.com/asakusuma/SugarCRM-REST-API-Wrapper-Class/

Now I want to link a specific Contact to a ProspectList (Target List). I guess this must be made with a set_relationship call, but the PHPClass I am using does not have that.

I have tried writing the function myself like this:

```
public function set_relationship($module_ids, $module_names, $related_ids, $link_field_names){
    $call_arguments = array(
        'session' => $this->session,
        'module_names' => $module_names,
        'module_ids' => $module_ids,
        'link_field_names' => $link_field_names,
        'related_ids' => array($related_ids)
    );

    $result = $this->rest_request(
        'set_relationship',
        $call_arguments
    );

    return $result;
}
```

And then calling it like this:

```
$c->set_relationship(
    $target_list['id'],
    'ProspectLists',
    $data['id'],
    'Contacts'
);
```

But it does not work. Does anyone know how to make a REST/Soap call to connect a contact to  a target list ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've finally figured it out, I've used the function from Kare's answer:

```
public function set_relationship($module_name, $module_id, $link_field_name, $related_ids){
    $call_arguments = array(
        'session' => $this->session,
        'module_name' => $module_name,
        'module_id' => $module_id,
        'link_field_name' => $link_field_name,
        'related_ids' => array($related_ids)
    );

    $result = $this->rest_request(
        'set_relationship',
        $call_arguments
    );

    return $result;
}
```

But I had to make the call differently:

```
$c->set_relationship(
    'Contacts',
    $contact_id,

    'prospect_lists',
    $target_list_id
);
```

I hope this will help someone

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two issues based on your information.

1. Module might not be [public](http://www.sugarcrm.com/forums/f6/problem-prospectlists-module-set_relationship-web-service-41137/), which is required for REST/SOAP API.
2. The argument names seem wrong according to the [documentation](http://developers.sugarcrm.com/docs/OS/5.5/-docs-Developer_Guides-Sugar_Developer_Guide_5.5-Chapter%202%20Application%20Framework.html#9000526).

Method with updated arguments:

```
public function set_relationship($module_name, $module_id, $link_field_name, $related_ids){
    $call_arguments = array(
        'session' => $this->session,
        'module_name' => $module_name,
        'module_id' => $module_id,
        'link_field_name' => $link_field_name,
        'related_ids' => array($related_ids)
    );

    $result = $this->rest_request(
        'set_relationship',
        $call_arguments
    );

    return $result;
}
```

And the call is

```
$c->set_relationship(
    'ProspectLists', 
    $target_list['id'],
    'contacts',
    $data['id']    
);
```